# How do I test a file reader?

Tags: unit-testing, language-agnostic, integration-tests, file-handling

I am working on a project with a few file formats. Some formats are specified by .xsds, others by documentation on their respective websites, and some are custom in-house formats that have no documentation. Mwahahahaha.

**What's the problem?**

I would like to test my file readers, but I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing this. The flow of the application is as such:

```
file.___  ===> read by FileReader.java ===> which creates a Model object
```

where the `FileReader` interface is

```
public interface FileReader {
    public Model read(String filename);
}
```

The `Model` has a number of attributes that are populated when the file is read. It looks something like

```
public class Model {
    List<String> as;
    List<String> bs;
    boolean isAPain = true;
    // ...
}
```

**What have I tried?**

My only idea was to create file "generators" for each file format. These generators are basically builders which take in a few variables (eg. number of comments to generate in a file), and output a sample file which I then read in and compare the resulting `Model` with the variables I used to initially generate the file.

This has a few problems, though:

- The files that it generates don't *look* like real files. The generator is in no way aware of context.
- It's hard to recognize if the generator has generated for edge cases since I'm the one manually setting the variables. This method is barely better than me creating a dozen sample files.

Are there any better ways to do this?

EDIT: Changed unit to integration since that's what I actually mean.

EDIT2: Here is an example of the edge cases I mentioned.

Each file represents a graph made up of vertices and edges. These vertices and edges can be attached in different ways, so:

```
v1 -- e1 --> v2 <-- e2 -- v3
```

is different from

```
v1 -- e1 --> v2 -- e2 --> v3
```

in that the direction of the edges matter. I'm not sure if this is in the scope of the question, but it's hard to think up all of the pertinent edge cases when I manually set the number of vertices, number of edges, and just generate the connections randomly.

Comment: [Data-driven testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_testing) comes to mind. Can you give concrete examples of edge cases (based on the edge cases that could possibly be triggered in the actual `FileReader` implementation)? Example: given the edge cases found in [image file formats](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html), for each table entry, if the row/column combination of properties are supported, there should be at least one test case (a data file) covering that combination.

Comment: @rwong I added an example but I'm not sure if it gives you an idea. I guess my problem is a common one with edge cases, ie. Have I missed any? Although, data-driven testing looks interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I just noticed this, but my edge cases literally are _edge_ cases.

Comment: Why not hand-craft test files, and then always run against the same ones?

Comment: @Bobson That's a bit worse than using a generator. In that case I might miss edge cases (as I probably am missing now), but I also might introduce errors in my typing. And with huge files, creating them on my own would take quite a while.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First, lets talk about what your goals are:

- you obviously don't want to test "file formats" - you want to to test your different `FileReader` implementations
- you want to find as many different types of errors as possible by automatic tests

To reach that goal in full, IMHO you have to combine different strategies:

- first, real unit testing: your `FileReader` implementations will consist of many different parts and functions. Write small tests which test each of them in isolation; design your functions in a way they don't really need to read the data out of a file. These kind of tests will help you to test most of your edge cases.
- second, generated files: those are what I would call integration tests. Such files will help you to track down failures different from point 1, for example, combinations of specific parameters, errors in file access etc. To create good test cases, it will also be helpful to learn about some classic techniques like grouping test cases into equivalence classes or boundary value testing. Get a copy of [this book by Glenford Myers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118031962) to learn more about that. The [Wikipedia article about software testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing) is a good resource, too.
- third, try to get real-world data: it can be hard to verify that these files are evaluated correctly by your `FileReader`s, but it may be worth it to do this since it often finds bugs not revealed by the first two strategies. Some people would call these kind things also "integration tests", others prefer "acceptance tests", but in fact the term does not really matter.

IMHO there is no "short-cut" approach which would bring you the benefit of all three strategies "for the price of one". If you want to detect edge cases as well as failures in standard cases as well as real-world cases, you have to invest at least some - more probably a lot - effort. Luckily, all of those approaches can be used for creating automatic, repeatable tests.

Beyond that, you should make sure your `FileReader`s don't mask any errors when reading that data - create in-built checks/assertions, throw exceptions when something goes wrong internally etc.. This gives your testing code a much better chance to detect errors, even when you don't have an explicit test file or test case for an unexpected situation.

Comment: Awesome answer, and I'll edit the title of my question to better reflect. Thanks!